# Can't create Web3 websocket connection successfully

Tags: web3js, websocket

I use latest `Web3` version (1.6.1) code in Node.js [as provided in docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3.html#example-local-geth-node). But when I run:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3( new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://dex.binance.org/api/ws'));
web3.onopen = function (evt) {
    console.log('WS opened');
}
```

it never connects.  When I try plain WS:

```
var WebSocket= require('ws');
var WS = new WebSocket('wss://dex.binance.org/api/ws');
WS.onopen = function (evt) {
    console.log('WS opened');
}
```

It works. What is the issue and how to make Web3 to work with WebSockets.

---

(note, I've tried [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54770/web3-websocket-connection-to-infura) but neither those codes work, and I dont want to use 2years old version package which was "working")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All available end-point rpc url are here https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html. HttpProvider works well. For Websocket run your own BSC Full node or Light Node.

Comment: Thanks for answer. yeah, i was searching for Websocket. Can you point me any good tutorial for running Light Node (i dont even know about them).

Comment: https://docs.binance.org/light-client.html use this tutorial for light node, only websocket provider lets you get pending transactions

Comment: Saman, many thanks to you !  I've awarded & upvoted the answer. I've successfully connected WS and now getting pending transactions. But my last question, as I am getting tons of new transactions: how to specifically check pending transaction in my token's pool? i.e.   `wbnb/mycoin` (contract address `0x123456....`).   I've also achieved getting transactions from txpool [(example here)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80689/get-each-transactions-from-response-of-txpool-getcontent)  but it's polling version.